# Material UI 5.0 : When autocomplete value is empty every items are selected

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

### Current Behavior

When the Input is null the style is highlight as grey light (something like this)

[image]

Here is my current code

```
<Field
  name="day"
  render={({ input }) =>
      <Autocomplete
         options={this.days}
         getOptionLabel={(option) => {
              return option.toString() 
          }}
          {...input}
          onChange={(e, val) => {
              input.onChange(val);
          }}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
              if (value === "" || value === option)
                  return true;
          }}
       renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Day" variant="outlined" />}
      />
} />
```

Note : I use "Field" wrapper for react-final-form (cause mui-rff didn't upgrade yet to MUI 5.0)

### Expected Behavior

On this picture, when I select a value, it match to my option's array and the style come back to normal.

[image]

### Context

Chrome: 94.0.4606.71

Comment: You should check this function `isOptionEqualToValue`, which is returning `true` for all options, if the `value` is empty, which it should not, in case of empty value.

Comment: If I don't use this function and return true when it's "null", I have a warning in chrome and say that empty string ' "" ' doesn't match any options. But in my case, I want to keep a default value empty.

Comment: You can initialize the value as `null` or `first option` in the autocomplete to get rid of the warning. Some discussion on the [MUI repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18514)

Comment: The problem is, I still have the problem and moreover, it displays a blank due to empty string added. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: If your value is empty, the initial autocomplete will be empty. 
Although, if you choose to have some option selected, when autocomplete renders, you can assign that value to the `value` prop. E.g. this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/controllablestates-material-demo-forked-0dk0p?file=/demo.js) has both options, either some pre selected value or `null` value (which is commented).

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution and thanks to you too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

I needed to move `{...input}` as first prop before `options={this.days}` by adding this option : `value={null}`.

Take care where you declare `{...input}`.